How to capture switch generated traffic on Catalyst 4500X
I have a Catalyst 4500X. I want to capture traffic associated with the DHCP relay service which is running on the switch.
I created the acl:
Extended IP access list capture
    30 permit udp any any eq bootps
    40 permit udp any any eq bootpc

I started a capture of the traffic on the vLAN interface:
monitor capture vlan146 file location bootflash:146.pcap vlan 146 both access-list capture
monitor capture vlan146 start

I tried monitoring both the vLAN interfaces (the client side and server side) for DHCP relay. In all cases, I only see traffic inbound to the switch. I do not see any of the traffic the switch is generating as part of its DHCP relay process.
I read a little about cef and process-switched on routers and some special things around capturing traffic generated by the router. Does this apply to the Catalyst switch? How do I capture this traffic that originates from the switch?

The relay traffic will be different since it is encapsulated in unicast packets to be sent to the DHCP server.

@RonMaupin Can you clarify? I understand it unicasts the packet. My access-list still covers that. I do see these unicast packets but only when they are inbound to the switch from the DHCP server.

You could skip the access list and load the capture into wireshark and filter it more easily there.
